# Save Key Pair - From Terminal - Not To Persistent Storage - Tails

Tags: terminal, usb-flash-drive, gnupg, tails, kleopatra

So . . . I am not using the persistent storage since it defeats the whole point of Tails. I am trying to save my PGP key pair to a secondary thumb drive (not the one tails is on) to be able to either use in a different OS or next time I log into Tails.

How do I do that from terminal after creating the key pair.

I am using  the GitHub create keypair step by step and it says exporting, but I want to get the key pair on to a secondary thumb drive (not tails/persistent storage drive) and not sure how to make that work.

Has anyone else tried this? Does it work? If so, tell me how please? lol

Thank you in advance!!!